# MetaMask can't submit transacion

Tags: android, ethereum, metamask, wallet-connect, bep20

- When a user using walletconnect on our dapp
- sends a transaction (calling transfer method of smart contract of BEP-20 token)
- the transfer popup show up but nothing happens after confirm button click (reject is able to click)

- Everything worked fine last week but failed yesterday for some reason. (same account but works well on metamask chrome extension.)

[image: Confirm button isn't processing payment]

Expected behavior:
User can click confirm and process the payment.

Smartphone:

- Device: Google pixel 4a / Google pixel 6a / samsung SM-G960F
- OS: Android13 / Android13 / Android 10
- Metamask App Version: v5.9.0(990)

Does anyone have ideas of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Metamask's transaction count is wrong and therefore your transaction nonces are set incorrectly?

Go to Settings > Advanced and click "Reset Account".

Comment: I was thinking about it though.. but still not work after reset account